# Typscript keeps throwing Property 'children' does not exist on type 'FC<ProvidersProps>' even after providing type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have provided the interface for the props but still its throwing

**Property 'children' does not exist on type 'FC'.**

```
'use clilent'

import React, { FC, ReactNode } from 'react'
import { Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast'

interface ProvidersProps {
  children: React.ReactNode
}

export default function Providers(props: FC<ProvidersProps>) {
  return (
    <>
      <Toaster position="top-center" reverseOrder={false} />
      {props.children}
    </>
  )
}
```

I had typscript@5.0.4 changed it to 4.9.6. Still not working

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `props: FC<ProvidersProps>` says that `Provider`'s **props** are a function component. They aren't, `Providers` itself (not its props) is a function component.

You have several options.

If you want to use `FC`, use it as the type of the function itself:

```typescript
const Providers: FC<ProvidersProps> = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Toaster position="top-center" reverseOrder={false} />
            {props.children}
        </>
    );
};

export default Providers;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/EQVwzgpgBAxgNgSwgOwC7ANwCgsILYAOA9gE6pQBKEAhjKgDRQDeUAYgMJQC+UAZiUTxRgJGnUy5CpciwAqRamFQQS3PgKEixqALQALIrtQKlE3GhW9a0AAoCAbggAmKsHaIEwzLFF+w9CHBOosgAXJTaAHRUtKgAckQuWFw4METISlDuji4kYOEcADzZzq7ungB8UAC8UAAUBAKeAJQ1VUw+fqKoICTI9Z1+foUVg0PjhfKKyqrEYAioCOnVwMYEOjAoM8BQovauEADyJLnVTFZwkDwA9KPj98yNHmCRMAFBISkPUIW3Y83YLjYLAQAAexDIUBcVhAcHIJVyYGwQA)

Alternatively, don't use `FC` (there's no requirement to):

```typescript
export default function Providers(props: ProvidersProps) {
    return (
        <>
            <Toaster position="top-center" reverseOrder={false} />
            {props.children}
        </>
    );
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/EQVwzgpgBAxgNgSwgOwC7ANwCgsILYAOA9gE6pQBKEAhjOQGYlF5TAk12a6GnkDeUACpFqYVBBJQAvlEbNW7WqgC0ACyIrUIsV1xoJ9WtAAKTAG4IAJhLCmiBMFD5Yor2KoRxL7ZAC5KHKgAdFRKAHJE1lhSOBAAHsRkUNaGIHAMIMh0CETIUHYW1iRgABQETA7+BVY2dg4AlE4ubuyoICR5Jc1ubgA8AHzdPcO9wqLiksRgCKg5yAC8wFoEyjAoE8BQ7GY2EADyJEXzfIZwkDIA9IPDN07l9mBBMB5ePjG3UL1XQ-XYMUA)

All `FC` really buys you is protection against forgetting to return something appropriate from the function (or returning something inappropriate). Another way you can do that is to provide a return type — `ReactNode` if you're never going to return `null` (which is rare):

```typescript
export default function Providers(props: ProvidersProps): ReactNode | null {
    return (
        <>
            <Toaster position="top-center" reverseOrder={false} />
            {props.children}
        </>
    );
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/EQVwzgpgBAxgNgSwgOwC7ANwCgsILYAOA9gE6pQBKEAhjKgDRQDelNdAckQCbQC+UAMxJE8UYCTbps+YmWZQAKkWphUEElH5CRYibVQBaABZFDqZasw4EadQNrQACsIBuCHiTDOiBMMyxQgbBGCHBcEsgAXKz6AHRU+pw8WLw4EAAesuQ89iBw5AIgyHQIRMhQ3m4eYAAUBMK+0ZXu6l4NYACU0Qkc3NAAPlDIeXD+QVASqCAk5TUB40EAPAB88wsLi0oqahrEYAiopcgAvMDmBAYwKDvAExAurRAA8iQex0z2cJD8APSr6+smPUfGBYjAQmEIqkAVBFn81lAOthUkA)